# What Biblical scripture is used to support the concept of waiting for God to give direction?

Tags: biblical-basis, christian-living

I am curious about the core idea of some Christians that they insist on waiting before "doing good".  What does scripture say about waiting for direction from God?

This is not a pro/con list or an attempt to evaluate the validity of the scripture or the concept of waiting for God.  I'd just like help identifying the scripture that supports the concept of waiting to act.

Answer (score 2):

Lamentations 3:25-27 (NIV)

> 25 The Lord is good to those whose hope is in him,
>       to the one who seeks him;
>   26 it is good to wait quietly
>       for the salvation of the Lord.

Micah 7:7 (NIV)

> 7 But as for me, I watch in hope for the Lord,
>       I wait for God my Savior;
>       my God will hear me.

Luke 12:36 (NIV)

> 36 like servants waiting for their master to return from a wedding banquet, so that when he comes and knocks they can immediately open the door for him.

Galatians 5:5 (NIV)

> 5 For through the Spirit we eagerly await by faith the righteousness for which we hope.

Comment: Always a bonus when you put old and new testament scripture together.